# Redirect Subdomain URL to another SubDomain with a folder in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

i want redirect a subdomain to another subdomain, but additionally i want it to redirect to a folder.

I tried this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="report" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="old.domain.com" negate="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://new.domain.com/admin-dashboard/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

With my code i only redirect to the new subdomain. But my folder is ignored.
What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I tried your rule, and it's working fine. Can you please your browsers cache and try again. Because browsers caching 301 redirects

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem :D

Comment: I've posted my comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is absolutely correct.

Problem is that all browsers will cache 301 redirects, because this redirect is **permanent**. To get around this, you'll just need to clear your browser cache.

If you put a permanent(301) redirect, that redirect will be cached in the browser for any visitors. You can’t clear the browser cache for your users, so if you need to change or undo a 301 redirect, the old redirect is still going to work until their cache expires.

> P.S. Do not put a 301 (permanent) redirect in place unless it is truly permanent! You can use 302 redirect for that